# Do cartridges have a unique (snmp) value? (Lexmark)

Tags: printing, snmp, oid

I'm currently developing an SNMP application for work. My boss wants me to somehow identify that a completely new cartridge has been installed and that you get a notice when an old one gets placed again in the printer. To do this, I need some kind of unique value that says that either a new or old cartridge has been placed in the printer. Now I can store this unique ID somewhere in a database, that's not a problem, the problem is: how can I tell if a completely new cartridge has been placed? By some kind of serial number?

I need to be able to retrieve this value by SNMP. (Yes, everything works for SNMP, so technically I just need the OID).

AGAIN: THIS IS FOR LEXMARK

The closest I can find to something being unique for a cartridge is an install date...

Any information on this is very helpful.

Comment: I doubt this information is available.  I was a system engineer for Lexmark years ago and don't recall anything like this.  I'd just track overall toner capacity and look for changes over a short period of time of a sizable %.

Answer (score 1):

using the iReasoning MIB-Browser I found out two OIDs that contain Information regarding serial numbers of cartridges:

currentSupplySerialNumber, OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.641.6.4.4.1.1.6
and
supplyHistorySerialNumber, OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.641.6.4.4.2.1.6

Don't know if this helps anymore, especially as the question is dated Apr-10 :-)

PS: I used a Lexmark MX511

Comment: For anyone visiting this, it's worth noting that those OIDs are exclusive to Lexmark's printers. The `641` part of the OID is Lexmark's private MIB, so these values will be unlikely to work on other printer manufacturers.